# How to show input field in a modal and submit it in a form in the main window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

We have a html form to edit articles with fields like "title", "author", etc.
One of the fields is called "tags".

An article can be tagged with multiple tags (eg "Economy", "USA", "Obama", "Oil").
We have a large number of tags (around 100 of these).

We're using Rails on the backend.  I have got this working using simple_form gem.
In my view file, I have

```
<%= @article.title %>

<%= simple_form_for @article do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :author %>
    <%= f.input :tag_ids, label: "Tags", collection: @tags, as: :check_boxes %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is very straight-forward and works.

Our requirement is a little bit different, however.  We want to display the tags checkboxes in a modal, and let the user make the selection there.  And when the user clicks "Save" button in the modal, his selections should be captured by the form in the parent window.
So when the user submits the form, the article's tags are persisted.

This is mainly a javascript/jquery/simple_form question.

How do I achieve this?

Specifically, can I still use simple_form to generate the checkboxes?
If not, how can I generate that in the modal?  Because the "form" declaration is in the parent window (not in the modal).

Should I have a hidden field in the form in the parent window, and when I click "SAVE"
on the modal, capture the selections and update the hidden field?

Are there any examples of how this is done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved this way:

- Make the checkbox invisible in the form (main window).
- When a user clicks the link to open the modal, the checkbox element is made
  visible and moved to the modal body.
- The user makes the checkbox selections in the modal, when he clicks on "Confirm"
  button in the modal, an event handler makes the checkbox element invisible and moves
  it back to the form.
- If the user reopens the modal, he'll see the checkbox selections he made before.
- When the form is submitted, the checkbox selections are persisted in the backend
  database.